# Symfony2 migrate data from database

Tags: database, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to migrate my users from an old database to the new Symfony2 Doctrine Database.

I have 2000 users, and my function works, but i'm getting an error when Doctrine try to map the new entity.

I get this error:

```
Warning: mb_convert_case(): Unknown encoding &quot;&quot;
```

I check my Username field in old database searching this character and i didnt found it.

Comment: &quot; is a special character and Punctuation is " . With this its name/meaning is quotation mark. I think your data containing quotation mark.

Comment: I checked it, there was 2 rows with &quote;, I was fixed it and the error still throwing.

Answer (score 0):

I think this error does not came from doctrine itself, because doctrine don't use mb_convert_case. Check your config files if they all use the utf8 charset.